# Putting inputs in a single row

Tags: html, css, jsf

***NOTE:*** The markup above is auto-generated by JavaServer Faces.
I have the following markup:

```html
<span style="display: block;">
    <input checked="checked" type="checkbox">ID 
        <select  size="1" > 
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="EQUAL" selected="selected">=</option>
        </select>
        <table style="display: inline-table;">
            <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                           <input name="cr" value="" type="text">
                     </td>
                 </tr>
            </tbody>
     </table>
</span>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ajmkery/)

As we can see from that demo, the inputs is not placed in a row.

[image]

How can I place them into a single line as follows:

[image]

Comment: Your markup is invalid. Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) and fix that first. It is also nonsense, you shouldn't have a table there at all, there's nothing tabular about it. You should also add label elements.

Comment: Why do you have such table next to the select? You can position text input using margin, positions absolute, padding etc.

Comment: @Quentin See, that markup is auto-generated. I'm using JavaServer Faces.

Comment: Use <br> tag before `<table>`.

Comment: @user3663882 — If I couldn't fix that, then I'd stop using JavaServe Faces immediately. It's awful.

Comment: use `vertical-align`

Comment: Can you also post the JSF code?

Comment: @Quentin: If one is using JSF components the wrong way (i.e. without having a basic HTML knowledge), it doesn't make JSF itself awful.

Comment: @BalusC — Hence "If I couldn't fix that".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions already, but if you dont want to alter your HTML code, then you can achieve it using some simple css rules. as following fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/5ajmkery/7/

**CSS**

```
span *{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px
}
table{
    padding:0;
    margin-left:20px;
    border-collapse:collapse
}
```

Comment: Yes also a good solution but OP is not very clear in what he can and can not modify...

Comment: this works. However, my recommendation to the OP is to remove the tables altogether. Only use them when necessary, tables can make the migration to a responsive layout later a nightmare. It's just as easy to use divs.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu: Yes, you are right using tables in responsive layout makes very difficult to manage. then my suggestion to OP is just remove table structure and put a div instead of table.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use table tag in your input???, otherwise you can use

```
<div>
 <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" style="float:left" />
 <label  style="float:left">ID </label>
 <select  size="1"  style="float:left" > 
  <option value="" >Select</option>
  <option value="EQUAL" selected="selected">=</option>
 </select>
 <input name="cr" value="" type="text"  style="float:left">
</div>
```

i hope that this solution help you

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure about limitations, but u could add display and margin style to table. It's a bit hacky..

```
<table style="display: inline-block;margin-bottom: -9px;">
        <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                       <input name="createRecipientDynamicGroupForm:j_idt240:8:j_idt253" value="" type="text">
                 </td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    <table style="display: inline-table;">
        <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <input checked="checked" type="checkbox">ID 
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    <select  size="1" > <option value="">Select</option>
                      <option value="EQUAL" selected="selected">=</option>
                    </select>                         
                  </td>    
                 <td>
                       <input name="createRecipientDynamicGroupForm:j_idt240:8:j_idt253" value="" type="text">
                 </td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
 </table>
```

Basically I have moved the 1st 2 elements in the table.

Comment: Is it possible to do without editing the markup structure? I can edit only style attribute.

Comment: @user3663882 Can you add inline style?